# Is it possible to roll my own Amazon Machine Image with a pre-Windows 2003 OS?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I've been researching EC2 over at Amazon Web Services and the website notes:

> "You are also empowered to use our
> bundling tools to upload your own
> operating systems."

Now I've been trying to find out if the only Windows version that is supported is Windows Server 2003 or if I would be able to virtualize an older version of Windows and mash it into an AMI?

Is that possible?
Has anyone achieved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EC2 only allows you to bundle your own open source *nix operating systems.  They won't let you run your own copy of Windows because of licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

only if you load a *nix platform with vmware then load windows onto a vm